# How to remove webform error message?

Tags: 7, webforms

How to remove webform error message? I need to be able to remove the error message form.

For instance, if I have an email field and for some reason did not pass the validation is not to show a message saying.

> The entered e-mail address "djhshsj" does not appear valid.

So my question is how I can remove that Drupal message?

**Update 1:** I had to render the error message below the button (I could not just move with CSS ). So I ended up doing my custom validation + error message.  And even though I have my custom validation, webform still validate if that field is correct or not. However, all I want to do is to remove the message **NOT** the validation.

Comment: "djhshsj" is indeed not valid, why would you want to remove this? You want to save invalid/useless e-mail addresses on your DB?

Comment: Why would someone put an invalid input there? perhaps they find giving an e-mail annoying or time consuming? Then you would be better off making the e-mail optional if that's what you want.

Comment: @NoSssweat, I have update my question with more content of the situation. So you can have an understanding, of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

[drupal_get_messages()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_messages/7) returns all the messages set using `drupal_set_message`, which also includes error messages set during form validation. **This also clears the messages.**

You can then add a custom validate handler to the webform by altering it by implementing [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7).

In your custom validate handler, call `drupal_get_messages()` to clear any error messages.

Comment: I try it on, `hook_form_alter` and I did not remove the webform error. However, all Krumos (dpm) errors was remove :s.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a Drupal module that gives you control over this. Its called Disable messages and can be found from the link below.

https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages

You need to enter a regex of the type of messages you need to hide in the configuration form.